# Join three tables with get sums of sales volume for each agent

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have table called PrimeClosureInformation and I want to get the sum of(Sales Volume) for each agentId and ExtraAgentId. I have some records have agentId  and ExtraAgentId values, I want to Dividing (Sales Volume) on each agentId  and ExtraAgentId  then add each new value to both agentId  and ExtraAgentId

This is the PrimeClosureInformation  table I selected the sum of SaleValue  for each AgentId  my question is if I have ExtraAgentId value I want to Dividing  the SaleValue on both for example in his table I want to get the SaleValue for mohamed and ahmed and if ahmed and mohamed both of them in the same record Dividing  the SaleValue then add Divided value to his SaleValue

```
PrimeClosureInformationPK  | SaleValue     | AgentNames    |  AgentId  |  ExtraAgentId | ExtraAgentName
             1             |  3802500.00   |   mohamed     |   80994   |   81009       | ahmed
             2             |  2145500.00   |    ahmed      |   98751   |   0           |
```

This is the select statement I was write it but this query is select sum of SaleValue  for each AgentId  only

```
SELECT DISTINCT sum(SaleValue)as SalesVolume, AgentNames
FROM [dbo].[PrimeClosureInformation], VW_User
where VW_User.FullName = AgentNames
    AND VW_User.UserIdLG = PrimeClosureInformation.AgentId
    AND VW_User.Status= N'active'
GROUP BY AgentNames
```

Comment: I have updated the select statement

Comment: Please show desired result with data. Your text explanation is not too clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UNION ALL to return all Agents (primary and extra) with their corresponding sales:

```
SELECT SUM(t.volume) as SalesVolume, t.AgentName 
FROM (
  SELECT AgentID, AgentNames AS AgentName, 
    SaleValue / CASE WHEN COALESCE(ExtraAgentID, 0) <> 0 THEN 2 ELSE 1 END volume
  FROM [dbo].[PrimeClosureInformation]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ExtraAgentID, ExtraAgentName, SaleValue / 2
  FROM [dbo].[PrimeClosureInformation]
  WHERE COALESCE(ExtraAgentID, 0) <> 0
) AS t INNER JOIN VW_User AS u
ON u.UserIdLG = t.AgentId 
WHERE u.Status = N'active'
GROUP BY t.AgentName
```

Comment: Post sample data in text format and expected results or make a fiddle so I can test.

Comment: If the ExtraAgentID is 0 when there is no ExtraAgentID then see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpivot the data using `cross apply` and then aggregation:

```
SELECT v.agentname, sum(SaleValue * factor) as SalesVolume
FROM [dbo].PrimeClosureInformation pci CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (AgentNames, AgentId, case when ExtraAgentId > 0 then 1.0 else 0.5 end),
             (ExtraAgentId, ExtraAgentName, case when ExtraAgentId > 0 then 0.5 else 0.0 end)
     ) v(AgentName, AgentId, factor) join
     VW_User
     ON u.FullName = v.AgentName AND
        u.UserIdLG = v.AgentId AND
        u.Status = N'active'
GROUP BY v.AgentName
```

Comment: Gives me this error Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint